# Using a non-English ubiquitous language?

Tags: dns, domain-driven-design, ubiquity

While discussing specifications and functional requirements for a recent project, we were talking with the domain experts about accounting terms in Dutch since the whole team and the customers were all native Dutch speakers.

When development started, we naturally implemented the domain classes and interfaces in English since we write all code in English. I noticed though that the follow-up meetings with the customers were confusing for them at times, especially when the developers were discussing implementation details and hence used the English terms.

What are your experiences with this?

PS: I know there are some other posts on Stack Overflow about whether or not you should write code in your native language, but this question is more about creating and using a ubiquitous language that all developers, customers and domain experts can understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is either a duplicate of or been covered fairly extensively by:

- [Naming conventions: Looking for alternative to mixing of English and domain/workflow terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455013/naming-conventions-looking-for-alternative-to-mixing-of-english-and-domain-workf);
- [How to manage non English speaking customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204506/how-to-manage-non-english-speaking-customer);
- [Coding in Other (Spoken) Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202723/coding-in-other-spoken-languages); and
- no doubt others.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know about [Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation). This may or may not fit your current situation.